# Color Label printing for Folder Filing

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am creating a report to take 6 digits and print them on a label.
The numbers are assigned a specific color, IE 0=yellow, 1=red, 2=blue  and so one. I can go and created the 6 different details.  I use HighLighting Expert to assign the rule for the value.  Is it possible to copy the setting(s) from 1 detail to another?  I will be using this same color coding for other labels.
I don't want to have to created this over again for every field and change human error!!
Thank you
Cameron

Comment: Are these digits that you evaluate to determine the color coming into the report as a column in the dataset returned by the database?

Comment: Digits are assigned  a specific color. In conditions I assign a color to a digit. This is done for all 10 digits.  I want to duplicate this into another data field for a total of 6 digits.  Without having to create this each time, it is 10 lines for each data element, I wish to copy it from a previous point.   I hope this clears up a bit.